# Alternative method to json_normalize that flattens lists within dictionaries

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary which contains a list that needs to be flattened to level 0.

Currently, I am using `json_normalize`, however, after some days of research I found out that it does not deal with lists and keeps it in one column.

Is there an alternative method to flatten the dictionary as well as lists? Or is the only possible solution through the creation of a function?

```
{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "active" : false,  
    "labelId" : [
        6422
    ],  
    "level" : [
        {
            "active" : true, 
            "level" : 3, 
            "actions" : [
                {
                    "active" : true, 
                    "description" : "Testing."
                }
            ]
          } 
       ]
  }
```

**Current Output:**
[image]

**Expected Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can systematically break it down using `json_normalise()` `explode()` and `apply(pd.Series)`

```
js = {'_id': 1,
 'active': False,
 'labelId': [6422],
 'level': [{'active': True,
   'level': 3,
   'actions': [{'active': True, 'description': 'Testing.'}]}]}

df = pd.json_normalize(js).explode("labelId").explode("level")
df = df.join(df["level"].apply(pd.Series), rsuffix="_l2").explode("actions")
df = df.join(df["actions"].apply(pd.Series), rsuffix="_l3")
print(df.drop(columns=["level","actions"]).to_string())
```

### output

```
   _id  active labelId  active_l2  level_l2  active_l3 description
0    1   False    6422       True         3       True    Testing.
```

### prefix by rename

```
js = {'_id': 1,
 'active': False,
 'labelId': [6422],
 'level': [{'active': True,
   'level': 3,
   'actions': [{'active': True, 'description': 'Testing.'}]}]}

df = pd.json_normalize(js).explode("labelId").explode("level")
df = df.join(df["level"].apply(pd.Series), rsuffix="_l2").explode("actions")
df = df.join(df["actions"].apply(pd.Series), rsuffix="_l3")
df = df.drop(columns=["level","actions"])
df.rename(columns={c:f"{c.split('_')[1]}_{c.split('_')[0]}" for c in df.columns if "_" in c})
```

Comment: Good idea, as the explode will create duplicates for multiple records, an addition to your code could be `df.drop_duplicates()subset = ["_id"], inplace = True` followed by a simple `print(df)`. I used this method and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: I find it strange that the data structure has `labelId` as a list...  doing two `explode()` can generate strange results.  `print()` was just me being lazy to paste output back into SO

Comment: is there an equivalent for prefix, so `rsuffix` for prefix as I need the text to go before the column name? E.g `_12level`

Comment: no... but you can always achieve this by renaming columns.  updated to demonstrate